# Selecting an array of rows using MySQLi

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to return results from an array of varying row numbers. Right now each row number in mysqli query is manually entered. How would you replace these values with the values of the `currentUsers` array?

```
$currentUsers = array('1', '3', '7', '10');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query))
{   
    $interestValue = ((int) "$row[1]") + 
                     ((int) "$row[3]") + 
                     ((int) "$row[7]") + 
                     ((int) "$row[10]");
    echo "$interestValue";
}
```

Comment: For sum you can use array_sum function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `while` loop use the array like this:

```
$interestValue = 0;
foreach ( $currentUsers as $i ) {
    $interestValue = $interestValue + (int) $row[$i];
}
echo $interestValue;
```

Comment: That works perfectly, though $row[i], had to be changed to $row[$i]. Thanks!